# Error in R packages Installation using Require

Tags: r

Please give me solution..

```
if (!require('SnowballC',character.only=TRUE)) 
    install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/SnowballC_0.5.1.zip', repos=NULL, dep=TRUE);
library('SnowballC')
```

when i use this command..I am getting message like

> Warning message: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only
>   = TRUE, logical.return = T RUE,  :   there is no package called 'SnowballC' Warning message: package 'SnowballC' was built under R
>   version 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

**Binary package compiled with different version of R**

```
Warning message:
package ‘SnowballC’ was built under R version 3.3.1
```

By default, R will install pre-compiled versions of packages if they are found. If the version of R under which the package was compiled does not match your installed version of R you will get the message above.

The solution is to download the package source and install by hand with e.g.:

```
#File name might be different

R CMD INSTALL SnowballC_0.5.1.tar.gz
```

Source: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1185